# Rails & Active Record: Complex SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A have 3 Models: Trailer, Movie, Release.  Trailer belongs_to a Movie, and a Movie has_many releases and has_many trailers.

I want to render the first trailer of each movie that has a release.

My approach was to create a scope in Trailer.rb:

```
scope :released, -> {
    joins(:movie).
    where("trailers.movie_id = movies.id").
    joins(:release).
    where.not( :release => nil )
  }
```

So that I could then call Trailer.released but my query is not working, instead of returning a collection, it's returning an active record relation.

1. Where am I going wrong with my query?
2. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: "instead of returning a collection, it's returning an active record relation." They're the same thing.

Comment: I guess what I'm meaning to say.. I'm expecting to receive an output of Trailer objects. But instead, I'm getting < AtiveRecord Relation #23232 > so I don't know where it's going wrong

Comment: @JacksonCunningham it most likely mean that your SQL is wrong. To make sure relation is valid, call `first`, for example, on it. It should spit out either the object or the error, saying what's wrong with the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :released, -> { joins(movie: :releases) }
```

would return all trailers, which movies have releases.

Comment: Wow, this looks simple. I'll make sure it works then accept, thanks!